# Analyzing reflected and transformed variables II

Tags: data-transformation

I've searched past posts and have not seen an answer to this specifically, perhaps because it is assumed to be known so it was not stated in previous related posts.

I have a very simple single variable model with a negatively skewed dependent variable Y.

The residuals from Y = b0 + b1X are non-normal, which, by my understanding will violate regression assumptions and impact my residuals and hence inferences but should not affect the properties of unbiassedness or consistency of my estimate 'b1'.  (correct me where I am wrong)

To make correct inferences it seems the practice is to reflect and log the dependent variable as such Y* = ln(1 + max(Y) -Y) and run the following regression:

Y* = b0 + b1X.

If I am correct so far then my primary question is do we interpret b from the model above the same as a traditional log lin model:

i.e. if ln(Y) = b0 + b1x

Then b1 is interpreted as the b1*100% change in Y due to a 1 unit change in x. or exp(b1) = the change in the 'geometric' mean of Y due to a 1 unit change in x.

If this is correct, does the same interpretation apply in the reflected and transformed case?

Thank you.

Comment: Because the "reflection" is straightforward to interpret, this question effectively is a [duplicate of questions](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=interpretation+log+add) about interpreting the "started log" $\log(1 + Z)$.

Comment: I'm not sure the question referenced as 'answered' was sufficient.Suggestions were made to use other transformations or a GLM framework, but the author specifically asked about the interpretation of 'beta' in terms of percentages.I did not find a specific yes or no confirmation in the comments regarding the correctness of interpretation. My question differs in adding a reflection, and specifically I'm interested in a reverse transform of 'b1'to get a 'units' interpretation (via exponentiation)which is a different question.I apologize if it is glaring before me but I have not found an answer.